# Error with recipient when sending a bounce email for a forwarded email in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

We have the following system set up in AWS SES: someone sends an email to our client (let's say enterprise1@ourclient.com) and our client forwards it to us (Plain-message forwarding to client1@ourcompany.com).

When we get the email, the Return-Path header is set to enterprise1@ourclient.com and the recipient list is set to client1@ourcompany.com.

Then, when we create and send a bounce using the SES client´s SendBounceAsync function (.Net core), we use the return-path address in the BouncedRecipientInfoList property of the SendBounceRequest. But then, we receive an error from SES telling us that the address is not in the recipient list:

```
Failed to generate a bounce for <7qg0qu8o6jhlult3uo4jupmvt04k4dbho8gb13g1>: Could not find email address <enterprise1@ourclient.com> in list of recipients for message ID <7qg0qu8o6jhlult3uo4jupmvt04k4dbho8gb13g1>
```

Clarification: in this case, we try to bounce using our client address as the sender (they want the users to see their address in the from). The domain is verified in our SES account. When we do this without the forwarding (the user sends the email directly to us and we bounce it), the bounce works.

How can we fix this? How can we send this bounce email?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SES restrictions. Have you moved out of the SES Sandbox as explained here:

[Moving out of the Amazon SES sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

Comment: The problem is that if we bounce without the mail forwarding (the user sends mail directly to us and we bounce it) it works. But it doesn´t work when we try to bounce using the account of our client, which is verified in SES.